# Magento 2: How to display custom attribute in product page?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento-2.2.5

How can i display an attribute under the title in magento 2.2.5
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the snippet of code below to the following file in your custom theme:

> Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
      <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.customattribute" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.main.title">
              <arguments>
                  <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">{at call goes here e.g. getCustomAtribute}</argument>
                  <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">{attribute code goes here}</argument>
                  <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                  <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="{attribute code goes here}"</argument>
              </arguments>
      </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Then flush your caches and the attribute should appear.